# (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Can you help me about this error on my logcat? 
http://pastebin.com/uSXruD54

Where:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference
```

on my Home class at line 79 which is:

```
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

http://pastebin.com/cixZ7d9d (MainActivity class, line 48)

I don't have any idea how setDrawerListener works sorry, I found the same problem here on stackoverflow: [How to rectify NullPointerException in v4.DrawerLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500963/how-to-rectify-nullpointerexception-in-v4-drawerlayout)

The answer says that it has to make sure that I'm using the same id for nav drawer and in layout file but I didn't made any changes on nav drawer because it's the activity itself that I chose in Android Studio, I just implemented tabs on it.

Comment: can u please post your xml code too.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and stack trace in the question itself, rather than linking off-site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drawer` is null, presumably because the `DrawerLayout` with ID `drawer_layout` is not in the `app_bar_home` layout. You should only be calling `setContentView()` once in `onCreate()`. The second call is completely replacing the `activity_home` layout with the `app_bar_home` layout. Your `DrawerLayout` is then no longer in the `Activity`, and the `findViewById()` will return null.

Instead, `<include>` the `app_bar_home` layout in `activity_home`, and remove the second `setContentView()` call.

Comment: Yup I suspected that because of the two setContentView() that I wrote and removing the other one which is:

setContentView(R.layout.app_bar_home); 

And it works now, thank you so much!